# How to maintain LaTeX environment, packages, etc. between different machines?

Tags: versions

I have several different computers that I work from; local workstations, remote servers, home personal machines, etc. How do you maintain some semblance of software version control across them so that a LaTeX document created on one machine can be compiled on another? For general programming, there are ways to isolate the programming environment so that packages, libraries, etc., are more portable (e.g. pyenv for Python); is there something like this for LaTeX?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the full current TeXLive from `www.tug.org` on every machine.
2. Put your local `texmf` tree in a Git repository and clone it from remote.

For #2, create `~/texmf/tex/latex/local` and `~/texmf/bibtex/bib`. Create a git repository in `~/texmf`. Put all your `.sty`, `.cls`, and even just `.tex` customization files in the `local` directory, and keep your bibliographies, or even just one master bibliography, in the `bib` directory.